# how to switch z index when working with react-spring

Tags: react-spring

https://codesandbox.io/s/64mwo66znr

I would like the z-index of a the selected element to be higher than all other elements, however only the "settings" element's z-index is always higher despite some of the few methods i've tried.

So when i click on either home or settings, the selected div should come out on top.